# How to have page only at "/" using react BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a React app with a homepage at `"/"` and other pages at `"/:pagename"`, but when I try to do this using a `<Switch>`, I get the content of my homepage PLUS the content of my other page at `"/:pagename"`. I'm not very familiar with React or BrowserRouter, but I think this is because `"/:pagename"` is also technically `"/"`. How can I make my homepage only show up when the base url has nothing appended to it?

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <body>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
      <Route path="/photography" component={PhotographyPage}/>
    </Switch>
  </body>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your router setup? This is going to be really hard to debug without it.

Comment: Do you want to use URL parameters or do you want to use a totally different component? In either case you need `exact` prop like in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exact` prop for your `/` path.

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/photography" component={PhotographyPage} />
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You are explaining a different situation from your code. In your code, you are trying to render a different component on the `/photography` path. But, in your explanation you are saying you want to use a path with URL parameters. In either case you need `exact` prop but the situations are different.

`exact` prop here tells the Router to match this path only. So it renders the `HomePage` component exactly if your path is `/`. If you don't use `exact` prop, Router tries to render `Homepage` every time it sees `/` path. So when you try to load `/photography` it first sees `/`, renders `Homepage` then it sees your full path and renders `PhotographyPage`.

Of course you can find more info in the [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy).